# How to test the value of a label

Tags: javascript, html

I have a list of news and I can modify the news. When I modify one she stay at her inital position (if she was at place 5 she stay here). But when I click "modify this new" a form pop to the bottom of the page and then when I submit the modifications I want to scroll to this modified new. To do that I would use something like

```
find position where label.text() == titleModified
```

then I could do

```
window.scrollTo(0,result of the line above);
```

For the moment I tried to do `document.getElementById` but it always bring me to the top of the page...

Thank you for helping me
PS: there is a link on Plunker to see the structure of news : https://plnkr.co/edit/mLCxPYaBR56KkEOLNF8F?p=preview

and this is my JS for the modification:

```
 'submit .modifyArticle'(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  const target = event.target;
  const textModif = target.textModif.value;
  const titreModif = target.titreModif.value;
  const photoModif = target.photoModif.value;
  const idModif = Session.get('idTemp');

  //test if values from the from are not empty or whitespaced
  if ((/\S/.test(textModif))||(/\S/.test(titreModif))) {
  console.log("2ème étape: dans body.js -> submit .modifyArticle");
  Meteor.call('articles.modify',idModif,textModif,titreModif,photoModif);
  Session.set('wantModif',false);


//here my new is modified so I want to scroll to her




//var titreModified actually contains the title after the modification but only for the first new...
  setTimeout(function(){
  var titreModified = document.getElementById("titreArticle");
  var position = titreModified.offsetTop;
  console.log("Y: " + position);
  console.log("var titreArticleModif: "+ titreModified.textContent);
}, 50)

[...]
```

EDIT (i'll put the solution here but the real hero is @alexr101):  First I had to add a class to my label `<label class="titreArticle">{{titre}}</label>`
  then this is the JS:

```
`setTimeout(function(){
  $('.titreArticle').each(function(i, obj) {
      if(obj.textContent.includes(titreModif)){
          alert("le titre devrait être: " + obj.textContent);
          var position = obj.offsetTop;
          window.scrollTo(0,position);
          return false;
      }
  });
}, 20)`
```

the timeout is here because it's not 100% real-time and I had to wait until the new title was put in the DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try getting the y position of the element like so:

```
//get modified element
var titleModified = document.getElementById("modifiedElement");

//get y position of element through offsetTop function
var yPosition = titleModified.offsetTop;

//Set scroll amount
window.scrollTo(0, yPosition );
```

Would that work?

Comment: I think it's on the right way but yeah i'll try to explain a bit better.
I have a lots of news and they have all the same structure https://plnkr.co/edit/mLCxPYaBR56KkEOLNF8F?p=preview . With your method the yPosition is always 734 (that's the last news). I think i really need to find a way to test that the title of the modified article is the same as the label value to find the right position you see ? And when i modify a new i don't change his position. thank you for helping @alexr101

Comment: Yeah, I see what you're saying. Are you able to get the text of the new title from the database, or wherever it's coming from? If you are you can probably get all the news elements by class...then check which one contains that text. I actually used something similar in a search question yesterday. titleModifiedByClass.innerHTML.includes(textFromDatabase);

Comment: I think you'd need to be more specific in your question, and show more code in order for us to help you better here. As it is right now, it's kind of hard, because the question seems to a bit too broad.

Comment: I'm still stuck. Actually i can take the new title but only for the first new (and always even if I modify the 5th it take the title of the first) someone could send me to the right way please ?

Comment: Ok, I saw your edited post...there shouldn't be a problem with finding it. If you have various elements with the same ID then it will just get the first element. Try adding a class to that element, and then search for that text through a iteration of those elements. Does that make sense? You might have to read a bit on how to access CSS classes and iterate through them with javascript or jquery.

Comment: You are the real hero ! I'll edit my post to put the solution but really thank you for all the time you gave to help me !! I wish i could give you a coffee. Thank you for all @alexr101

Comment: Don't worry about it, just glad I could help brother!!